# Verilog proper use of high impedance value?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, impedance

In verilog, what are some examples of when one should opt to use the high impedance value Z?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Whenever you need to model a tristate or open-collector (open-drain) driver, such as on a bidirectional signal or a tristate bus.